# Venn Diagram Probability Problem

Tags: probability

73 of the 86 passengers participated in at least one method of exercise.  36 people went roller blading, 44 people did indoor track, and 19 played football.  14 people went roller blading and indoor track, 11 people went roller blading and played football, and 9 people did indoor track and to play football.

I have started a Venn Diagram with the basics but, for example, if I put 11 people roller blading and football and then 14 people roller blading and indoor track then I already go over the 19 person limit for people who played football. I do not know where I am going wrong...

Comment: Well you haven't actually said what the question is so it's a bit hard to advise... but try starting with the number of people who did all three.  Since this is not given call it an unknown, say $x$, and work out other numbers in terms of $x$.  Hopefully you can then find an equation to solve, giving you the value of $x$... if that's what you need...

Comment: there are actual questions but I need to figure out how to draw the venn diagram first. All of these numbers need to fit within each circle of the venn diagram and add up to the corresponding amount for each sport, and then the entire venn diagram must add up to 73

Answer (score 2):

We know that $73$ people did one or more of the sports. And we also know that the total participation over all sports was $36+44+19= 99$. So there is an "overcount" of $26$.

[image]

The overcount will consist of the number of people who play two sports plus twice the count of those who play three sports. So

$$x+y+z+2A = 26$$

We also know the values of $x+A, y+A$ and $z+A$, and combining those we get:

$$x+y+z+3A = 14+11+9 = 34$$

This gives us $A=8$ and you can take it from there.